# Cannot connect to a shared network drive even that I am on the same subnet and all the other users can connect

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, windows-update, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an Windows Server 2012. I have shared folders on the Windows Server. The users map them by mapping as a Network Drive.
I do not have problems with any other user/Computer. Usually I access the shared folders through server name or IP Address. But, at a new lap top, I can not access it. I get the error:

PC is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions. The computer is on Windows 10 PRO 20H2 Version

1. I can ping the machine.
2. I can remote desktop connect to the machine.
3. The machine is on the same subnet
4. When I try with my firewall turned off the same happens.
5. I ensured: "Turn on network discovery" is set.
6. I uninstalled the antivirus at the client.
7. the computer is not member of the work domain but even when I connect it there is no difference
8. When I add the server IP with the username and password for the user at Credential manager,sometimes I am able to connect the network drivers, but after the restart I loose the connection and I have to do point 8 again and sometimes it works sometimes it does not.
9. I have tried also with other users, but again I have the same results...

What else I should try? Could it be related with the new update of Windows?
It did not happened before this kind of issue...

Looking forward to hear your ideas...

Answer (score 1):

What it fixed.
I did a reset of the password of the AD user.
I added the server name and server IP with the username and password at Credential Manager.